# Using VBA code to modify OptionButton.value is activating the control.Click() Sub

Tags: vba, excel

I have a userform with 2 OptionButton choices, and I'm modifying the form (hiding labels and controls, and resizing frame) for the default Option (name = BwaIsNew), but then restoring the full userform when Option #2 (name = BwaIsOld) is selected. (see separate question for background).

When Option #2 is selected I'm calling a fresh userform, and coding the change in value. But this coding of the value  `dlgInformation.BwaIsOld.Value = True` then triggers an event (?) that calls the `Sub BwaIsOld_Click()` code to run. This then sets up a perpetual loop.

What's the best way to solve this?

Problem code (the one looping) is:

```
Private Sub BwaIsOld_Click()  
Unload Me  
dlgInformation.BwaIsNew.Value = False  
dlgInformation.BwaIsOld.Value = True  
dlgInformation.Show  
End Sub
```

Update:

Thanks @Tim & @CommonSense. I'm still not quite there yet. What am I doing wrong? Here is the code

```
Public EnableEvents As Boolean

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub BwaIsNew_Click()
    Call changeform(280)
End Sub

Private Sub BwaIsOld_Click() 
    Unload Me 
    Me.EnableEvents = False 
    dlgInformation.BwaIsNew.Value = False 
    dlgInformation.BwaIsOld.Value = True 
    Me.EnableEvents = True 
    dlgInformation.Show 
End Sub
```

Comment: [Suppressing Events In UserForms](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/SuppressChangeInForms.htm)

Comment: Thanks @Tim & @CommonSense. I'm still not quite there yet. What am I doing wrong? Here is the code    `    Public EnableEvents As Boolean ` `    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()  Me.EnableEvents = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub BwaIsNew_Click()
    Call changeform(280)  
    End Sub

    Private Sub BwaIsOld_Click()

    Unload Me    

     Me.EnableEvents = False
     dlgInformation.BwaIsNew.Value = False
    dlgInformation.BwaIsOld.Value = True  Me.EnableEvents = True
    dlgInformation.Show
    End Sub
`

Comment: Don't put code in comments - it's too difficult to read...

Comment: Thanks for the edit @TimWilliams

Comment: The `Unload Me` line is because I want to resent the UserForm to it's default size.  I've set up a new question to set the context a little better >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47782832/vba-code-to-suppress-the-the-control-click-sub-event-handler  Thanks again for your assistance @TimWilliams

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually use that `EnableEvents` in the rest of your code.
BTW I would choose a different name from the built-in `Application.EnableEvents` property just for clarity.

```
Public EnableEvents As Boolean

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub BwaIsNew_Click()
    'don't respond to events triggered by BwaIsOld_Click
    If Me.EnableEvents Then 
        Call changeform(280)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub BwaIsOld_Click() 
    Unload Me '<< why do this here?
    Me.EnableEvents = False 
    dlgInformation.BwaIsNew.Value = False 
    dlgInformation.BwaIsOld.Value = True 
    Me.EnableEvents = True 
    dlgInformation.Show 
End Sub
```