# VBA code to suppress the the control.Click() Sub / event handler

Tags: vba, excel

OK. This is driving me nuts. I'm still getting a perpetual loop.
My previous question got me so far >>> [Using VBA code to modify OptionButton.value is activating the control.Click() Sub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47707808/using-vba-code-to-modify-optionbutton-value-is-activating-the-control-click-su/47764041#47764041)

I've rewritten some example code to try and nut this out.
I've set up a Boolean 'handler' as per other suggestions
(eg: [Suppress events in UserForms](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/SuppressChangeInForms.htm)).  (I've called it `SwitchOnEventResponder`)

When it gets to the code that is causing the click event to fire, the handler flips back to True (which allows a value change to activate the _Click() sub) just as the `OptionsDLG.OptionButton2.Value = True`
statement executes. WHY?

Code in the module:

```
Sub StartDLG()
Call changeframe(135)
'code to change the UserForm (to hide the text box)
Call PopulateText
OptionsDLG.Show
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = 0 Then Cancel = True
End Sub

Sub PopulateText()
' Populates text box with initial text
OptionsDLG.TextBox1.Value = "Enter your msg here"
End Sub

Sub changeframe(FormH As String)

OptionsDLG.Height = FormH
OptionsDLG.Label1.Visible = False
OptionsDLG.TextBox1.Visible = False
End Sub
```

UserForm "OptionsDLG" code:

```
Public SwitchOnEventResponder As Boolean

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
        Me.SwitchOnEventResponder = True
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton2_Change()
        MsgBox "Me.SwitchOnEventResponder = " & Me.SwitchOnEventResponder
        If Me.SwitchOnEventResponder = False Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()

 Unload Me
 Call changeframe(135)
 'code to change the UserForm
 Call PopulateText
 OptionsDLG.Show

End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()
 If Me.SwitchOnEventResponder = False Then
            Exit Sub
 End If

 Unload Me

 Call PopulateText

 Me.SwitchOnEventResponder = False
 MsgBox "Me.SwitchOnEventResponder = " & Me.SwitchOnEventResponder
 OptionsDLG.OptionButton1.Value = False
 OptionsDLG.OptionButton2.Value = True '<< This is where the loop starts. grrrr
 Me.SwitchOnEventResponder = True
 OptionsDLG.Show
End Sub

' This runs when the Ok button is clicked
Private Sub OK_Click()
    If OptionButton1.Value = True Then MsgBox "HAPPY"
    If OptionButton2.Value = True Then MsgBox "HAPPIER"
End Sub

' This runs when the cancel button is clicked
Private Sub Cancel_Click()
    ' Show the main dialogue
    Stop
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
            If CloseMode = 0 Then Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Comment: try to declare `Public SwitchOnEventResponder As Boolean` in separate module, not in userform. I use it  this way and its working.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why is the `Private Sub Userform_QueryClose` in the module and not in the Userform?

Comment: @Sphinx - I moved the declaration out of the userform into the module. Now the userform doesn't recognise the `Me.SwitchOnEventResponder = True` statement

Comment: @SilentRevolution - It's in both. For no good reason. I guess I only need it in the userform code.

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand the problem it will help to change your `MsgBox` message

```
MsgBox "Me.SwitchOnEventResponder = " & Me.SwitchOnEventResponder & vbCrLf & "OptionsDLG.SwitchOnEventResponder = " & OptionsDLG.SwitchOnEventResponder
```

[image]

`Me` refers to the current instance of an Object.  Calling `Unload Me` will remove this instance from the Userforms collection.  When you set a variable or control on a Userform that is not Loaded a new UserForm is auto-instantiated.  The original instance of the Userform `Me` does not refer to the the new Instance of the UserForm.

Changing `Me.SwitchOnEventResponder = False` to `OptionsDLG.SwitchOnEventResponder = False` will solve the problem.

I prefer to create a new instance of the Userform before unloading the current instance.   Using a With statement will ensure that all the variables and controls are fully qualified to the correct instance.

```
With New OptionsDLG
    .SwitchOnEventResponder = False
    .OptionButton1.Value = False
    .OptionButton2.Value = True
    .SwitchOnEventResponder = True
    .Show
End With

Unload Me
```